# Combine two simple android:id or (R.id)

Tags: android, android-layout

Fristly I am very new to android and I have two android:id .

For example: [ R.id.custom_font ] and [ R.id.product_name ]

In .java file

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/jcc.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(cFont);


adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name,  R.id.custom_font, products);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I put them together in a single text view it shows an error message [Attribute "android:id" was already specified for element "TextView"]

In .xml file

```
    <TextView

    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/custom_font"
    android:id="@+id/product_name" //Attribute "android:id" was already specified for element "TextView"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

How can I pass the two android:id in a single text view?

Or anybody if kindly help me [Download This](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/To-Use-Custom-Font.zip)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the same id for both `TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom_font);` and `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>`?

Comment: **"How can I pass the two android:id in a single text view?"** - You can't...it's as simple as that. What Ahmad says is true - you can only have one resource id for any UI element (widget). That's exactly why you are getting the error.

Comment: @Squonk I found about using custom font in android [here](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/) . Suppose here has an `android:id` **android:id="@+id/CustomFontText"** But in my project I already have an **android:id="@+id/product_name"** which display my product name in a list. **So how can I implement both together?** If I use `the both id` or `the same id` . The emulator shows an error message **"The application stopped unexpectedly. Please try again later!".** I am really helpless!

Comment: @Squonk Could you please help me testing the download link at Ahamed. I am still kind to him for is prompt suggestion but not yet he respond back. I would be grateful if any body help me! Could you please?

Comment: @Matthieu Thanks for your reputation. could you please help me?

Comment: Look at the other comments and answers and the link.. it is not possible to assign two IDs to the same view item. If you have a reason why you really need to do this, you should explain what that reason is...

Comment: @Matthieu I have a small app which display `product name` and another app which can change the `font style`. I want just changing the font style of the product name. [Here is the two Apps.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/To-Use-Custom-Font.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set one Id to an UI widget. Remove one of the Id's. You can use the same Id for your ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same answer as Ahmad, but based on the comments, you don't seem to get it, so change your XML like this (remove the line that gives the error):

```
<TextView
android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/custom_font"
android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Then change the Java code like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/jcc.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(cFont);


adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.custom_font,  R.id.custom_font, products);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If ever your problem is with the two arguments of the constructor for the ArrayAdapter that are the same that bothers you, try like this...

Change the XML like that:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/product_name">

<TextView
android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/custom_font"
android:textSize="15sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then you can keep the same Java code as what you had...

If that still does not solve it, I am really puzzled as to what your problem really is.